# Allow a windows service to interact with desktop in Perl

Tags: windows, perl, windows-services

I have a windows service running, part of its operation is to open up an internet explorer window. This all works fine, except the Internet explorer window (when called from the service) doesn't appear! You can see that it was successfully started and can see it in the task manager but it's like the window is hidden.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Win32;

my $prog="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
my $arg="";

Win32::Spawn( $prog, $arg, $pid );
```

Note: I cannot run that windows service as "Local System Account" which has an option "Allow Service to Interact with desktop", I had to specify the username  as in the pic attached for some other reason, but I logged in into the machine with same account (aa\tour).[image: windows service image]

Is there a way to see the iexplore window in foreground? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are running into [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation), a security enhancement that prevents applications launched from a Windows Service from showing up on a "regular" user's desktop. Once upon a time (pre Windows Vista) the ["Allow Service to Interact with desktop"](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#InteractWithDesktop) setting would enable your IE window to show up on the console session, but that no longer works as one would expect with isolation now in place.